# Code stops running after error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2013

Periodically, when I get a runtime error in VBA for Excel 2013, my code stops running. For example, the code in the Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) sub no longer executes when I make a drop down selection.

I've tried clicking the reset button in the IDE which often works but not always and I have to close Excel down and reopen it and then the code will fire.

There must be a way to reset without having to go through all of this.

Comment: You should post your code and the specific error message so that others can help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and your code crashes at some point after that, but before resetting to `True`, then any events will no longer be captured.

That `False` setting will persist even after resetting the VB project. The only way to reset it is to run some code to set it back to `True`.

You can run this from the VBE Immediate pane:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Whenever you turn off event handling in your code, it's a good practise to always include error handling, so you can turn event handling back on before your code exits.